# Add message animation on click

Tags: javascript

I want to add a 'Copied!' animation to my javascript that triggers when you click on a link. I want it to appear next to the mouse and disappear after 2 seconds of appearing.

I went hunting on the internet for similar animation examples but couldn't find anything.

Apologies if this is a tall order of a question.

```js
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
```

Comment: jQuery has a lot of good animation options. I just created a "fadingMessage" using this library. Also note that CSS3 has transitions... you should check it out

Comment: Use sweetalert2 https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to delete the element 2 seconds later, you can use `setTimeout`:

```js
setTimeout(() => inp.remove(), 2000);
```